# Retrieve synonyms list from database in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to configure Elasticsearch to retrieve synonyms list from database/sql instead of file?

Comment: What do you mean by database? ES? or another nosql/sql?

Comment: no, ES can't go direct to a table in a DB for synonym configuration

Comment: @Gibbs I've edit the question, yes, I mean sql

Comment: @Nate so ES is working only with files for synonyms, or it could be something else?

Comment: You can also manage them via API calls

Comment: Files is the recommended from the docs "However, it is recommended to define large synonyms set in a file using synonyms_path" https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html#_solr_synonyms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible.

ES supports file or online synonyms. It supports solr synonyms format..

[doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html)

But you can add all the synonyms along with original field as an array in ES. While querying, you can use that array field and retrieve the original field.

Comment: And I suggest you to consider @Nate's point of handling it API if it really demanded by management. You can read from sql db and query your field is one of them.